# scroll event is not triggered on document in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I bound the scroll event on document via jquery, however I found it is not triggered in IE8 but works in other browsers such as chrome, firefox and IE9/10/11. is it an IE8 bug?

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    console.log('doc scrolls'); // nothing is printed in IE8 console actually
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try using window

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   //do something on scroll
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    console.log('doc scrolls');
  });
```

Comment: @YonggooNoh  Yes, are your registerring event on '$(window)' ??

Comment: YES, but I tried that using emulator in IE 11. Does this matter to this problem?

Comment: yes, I would recommend to directly test the code in IE 8. It should work